# What's the difference between Uncorrelated Random Variables and Independent Variables?

Tags: math, statistics

I'm seeking a simple yet detailed answer that doesn't rely on mathematical formulas. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this question on stats.stackexchange.com instead, rather than here.

Comment: Thanks Peter never heard of stats.stackexchange.com before. I will do so next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming in the question you're referring to Independent **Random** Variables.
Independent variables can be defined in terms of conditional probabilities ([ref here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory)))

Correlation on the other hand is a measure of linear dependency between the variables. The value is between -1 and 1 where 1 indicates the variables are perfectly positively (increasing one increases the other) correlated.

A correlation of 0 would indicate there is no linear relationship between the variables. ([ref here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)).

If 2 variables are independent then the correlation would be 0 but vice versa is not necessarily true.

Comment: So are uncorrelated random variables just a pair of variables with a correlation coefficient of 0?

Comment: Also are uncorrelated random variables that are not independent random variables just a pair of variables with a relationship which exists but isn't linear?

Comment: Uncorrelated random variables means correlation coefficient is 0. For your second the answer is yes, as correlation only captures linear relationship between the variables.

Answer (score 2):

@ANIRUDH BUVANESH's answer is fine. Personally I like to see examples and pics, perhaps this [image]
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#/media/File:Correlation_examples2.svg). There you can see different variables and their correlations.

The text from the image: "Several sets of (x, y) points, with the Pearson correlation coefficient of x and y for each set. The correlation reflects the noisiness and direction of a linear relationship (top row), but not the slope of that relationship (middle), nor many aspects of nonlinear relationships (bottom). N.B.: the figure in the center has a slope of 0 but in that case the correlation coefficient is undefined because the variance of Y is zero."